# How to set a program that count similar items in a string?

Tags: python, list

I have this list

```
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
```

I need a function that would tell me that there is 3 gold coin, 1 dagger and 1 ruby in the dragon loot.

Comment: use `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Counter container.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(dragonLoot)

for item in c:
    print(f'{item} {c[item]}')
```

This code would return:
gold coin 3
dagger 1
ruby 1

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter